# Urql error: cannot read property of variable name undefined, and I defined it properly

Tags: javascript, react-redux, graphql, react-hooks, urql

Here is  my problem:

```
const GraphComponent = () => {
  const { GraphQuery } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const query = `
  query($input: MeasurementQuery ){
      getMeasurements(input: $input){
      metric,
      value,
      unit,
      at
      }
  }
  `;
  const [{ fetching, data, error }] = useQuery({
    query,
    variables: {
      GraphQuery,
    },
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fun = () => {
      if (fetching) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) console.log(error.message);
      if (!data) return;
      console.log(data.getMeasurements);
    };
    fun();
  }, [fetching, error, data]);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default GraphComponent;
```

The 'GraphQuery' variable is an object that looks like this

```
obj = {
      metricName: deets,
      after: Date.now() - 36000000,
      before: Date.now(),
    };
```

The graphql query on the playground that accepts variable looks like this

```
{
  getMeasurements(input:{metricName:"tubingPressure", after:1587371198855,before:1587370098855}){
    metric,
    value,
    unit,
    at
  }
}
```

But the error I keep getting is

```
[GraphQL] Cannot read property 'metricName' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

inside `useQuery` try and change your code to:

```
variables: {
      input: GraphQuery,
    },
``
```

Comment: there is a special place in heaven reserved for you, thank you so much!!!